# How to reschedule an at job to run earlier?

Tags: scheduling, at

Suppose I had scheduled an `at` job to run 3 hours later:

```
$ echo command | at now +3 hours
$ atq
9     Mon Dec  5 14:00:00 2016 a nr
```

but having passed 1 hour I change my mind, and then need to run that specific job `#9` from queue `a` immediately, that is, 2 hours earlier than the time at which it is scheduled to run.

How can I do it?

I know I can print the job command to `stdout`, copy and paste it to the command line, run it manually, and then remove job `#9`:

```
$ at -c 9
command
$ command
$ atrm 9
```

But this amounts to running *another* job, not `#9` from queue `a`.

Comment: I think the answer is that you can't. I guess being able to reschedule a job without changing the job number isn't a very commonly requested feature.

Comment: I see. Would it be possible to reschedule it, though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

- [First, there is a method over on stackoverflow.com about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304631/rescheduling-an-at-job)

  - It does preserve the job number
- Second, using at to duplicate the job at a new time:

  ```
  at -c 9 | at now + 1 hour -- reschedule job 9 from whenever to now + 1 hour
  atrm 9                    -- Removed the old job
  ```

Comment: Thanks. Would you provide the link to the other answer, please?

Comment: I've seen the other answer, but I really love the simplicity of this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the accepted answer, here is a convenient script (I call it `atmv`):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/bash

# Idea taken from here:
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/331789/68456

set -euo pipefail

atlist() { atq | sed 's/^/  /'; }

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Syntax: atmv job_num new time arguments"
    exit 1
fi

job_num="$1"
shift

if [ "$(atq | cut -f 1 | grep "$job_num" | wc -l)" != "1" ]; then
    echo "Error: There is no job with number \"$job_num\"."
    echo "Pick one of these:"
    atlist
    exit 2
fi

at -c "$job_num" | at "$@" 2> /dev/null
atrm "$job_num"
echo "Done! This is the new list of at jobs:"
atlist
```